# Check if correctly spelled

Tags: text-processing

For my `CheckCodingGuidelines` script. I want:

```
#ifndef GAIN_MODULE_H
#define GAIN_MODULE_H
```

To pass

And:

```
#ifndef __GAIN_MODULE_H
#define __GAIN_MODULE_H
```

To fail (`echo: Error Rule25 at $line`)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
  /^[[:blank:]]*#[[:blank:]]*(define|ifndef)[[:blank:]]+_/ {
    print "Error Rule25 at " FNR
  }' file.h >&2
```